# Click event passes key modifier to its function. Change event not. How to do it?

Tags: javascript, onclick, onchange, addeventlistener, dom-events

Click event passes key modifier (e.g., shiftKey) to its function. Change event not. Is there some way how to do it?
Use case: when I click OR ENTER standard select(box) option, triggered function will receive shiftKey true or false value and I can act upon it.

Comment: A click event is a mouse event; a change event is not a mouse event. A change can be triggered by a lot different things, it does not make sense to have properties about the mouse inside of the change event. You will have to handle changes made by the mouse differently if you want modifier keys to have an effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- added two listeners to select element: keydown, click
- both keydownFunc and clickFunc evaluates whether shift is pressed
- final Func receives this value and work with it